# Optimizing weighted matrix sum / trace

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I need to optimize sum $\sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \beta_j u_{i,j} \to \min$, where $\alpha_i \in [0,1]$ and $\beta_j \in [0,1]$ are variable and $u_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ are given.

In other words, I need to find vectors $\alpha,\ \beta$ with values in $[0,1]$ such that the weighted matrix sum is minimal.

The sum can be rewritten as

- $\alpha\ U \beta^T \to \min$,
- $\sum_{i,j} (\alpha^T\beta )_{i,j}\ \cdot\ u_{i,j} \to \min,$ (*)
- $\text{trace}(\beta^T\alpha\ U) \to \min.$

Are there ways to solve this other than optimize numerically? At first I thought it can be solved using linear programming, for example for the case (*), but I need to find two vectors, not one.

Comment: You want to minimize an indefinite quadratic form over a box. This is a non-convex quadratic program.

Comment: This I think is a combinatorial problem. Since $\alpha^T U\beta$ is bilinear and the feasible region is a closed hypercube, the global minimum is attainable at the corners of the hypercube, i.e. you may assume that the values of $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ are either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you, that was very helpful! I found a good review of the problem here https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470400531.eorms0107